# Gitlab CI can't install gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, continuous-integration, bundler, gitlab

I'm building a rails app using gitlab ci and a few issues came up.

- The first was it couldn't find `rake` to run the tests

  - I installed rake on my digital ocean manually to solve this
- Then it was complaining the `gitlab_ci_runner is not in the sudoers list`

  - I added `gitlab ci` to the sudoers list which solved that problem

Now when running `bundle install` it is complaining that `Bundler::GemspecError: Could not read gem` for every single gem unless I install them myself.

Am I missing something with the way I setup gitlab ci?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'gitlab_ci_runner' w/o switching user.

```
sudo -u gitlab_ci_runner -H bundle install --deployment
```

If you're root user that has a password (meaning your NOT using a SSH-Key) use this to switch back to root user.

```
su
```

Comment: The ci script can't do these operations.